# Delphi tstream: strange behaviour on create

Tags: delphi, abstract-class, abstract, tstream

I am new of Delphi. In the documentation of TStrem class, i read it is an abstract class.
So i think the compiler goes in error when i try to create it with

```
stream := TStream.Create();
```

Why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Delphi language doesn't really have any formal concept of abstract class.

It is true that you can define a class to be abstract:

```
type
  TMyClass = class abstract
  end;
```

But you can perfectly well instantiate this class. In fact `class abstract` in Delphi is a feature used only by the long abandoned Delphi .net compiler.

A more useful definition of an abstract class is one that contains `abstract` methods. If you attempt to instantiate such a class, then a compiler warning will be emitted. Those warnings can be promoted to errors by way of a compiler option, if you wish.

When the documentation refers to `TStream` as being abstract it in fact means that it is "conceptually" abstract. In fact it does not even have any `abstract` methods, so by my definition above it is not abstract.

I'm really not sure why `TStream` does not contain abstract methods. I would suggest that the `GetSize`, `SetSize`, `Read`, `Write` and `Seek` should really be declared `abstract`. I suspect that if the class were being designed today then they would be declared `abstract` and likely they are not for historical reasons.

Instantiating `TStream` is a very common mistake made by programmers less experienced in the Delphi RTL. Once the mistake has been made a couple of times, the lesson is usually learnt. Unfortunately the system provides no easy way for this mistake to be flagged up. Each and every new programmer just has to learn the hard way.

Comment: I think that they wont change some methods to abstract because there could be issues with some (maybe big and/or old) projects that actually use them

Comment: @AlbertoMiola *I suspect that if the class were being designed today then they would be declared `abstract` and likely they are not for historical reasons.*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If TStream is abstractly conceptually, the instance is conceptual error too. If I forget it and use TStream and its methods directly (ie not the TMemoryStream methods), the code works well. Or not?

Comment: No, if you instantiate a `TStream`, then none of its methods do anything useful.

Comment: `Read` and `Write` were abstract at least as late as Delphi 2005. However, `Seek` was not abstract anymore because `TStream` was extended to support 64-bit offsets, which the original `Seek` couldn't do. The base class uses some tricks to figure out which `Seek` was overridden, and then makes the other method call the overridden one. I assume something similar was done for `Read` and `Write` at some point, so that descendant classes wouldn't necessarily have to implement _all_ the virtual methods, just whichever ones were most convenient.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 
"none of its methods do anything useful" What do you mean?
I use a CreateBlobStream, a function of the TFDQuery class. It returns a TStream type.
My code is:

function getSizeOfStream(TFDQuery q):int64;
var stream:TStream;
begin
stream:=TStream.Create;
stream:= q.createBlobStream('blob_field');
result:=stream.size;
end;

The compiler compiles and the code returns the size of stream.

Comment: I mean the virtual methods implemented in `TStream`. Descendent classes, such as that returned by `CreateBlobStream` override those virtuals to do real work.

Comment: Can i know the type of the discendent class of TStream returned by CreateBlobStream?  Thanks a lot @DavidHeffernan

Comment: You don't need to know that. It's quite possibly a private type, defined in the implementation section of a unit and so not available to you. You can query `ClassType` on any instance to obtain the runtime type. But I repeat, you don't need to know this. The entire point of the `CreateBlobStream` abstraction is that the runtime type is not something you should be caring about.